# java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10194 does not have permission to content://com.microsoft.office.onenote/clip [user 0]

Tags: android

The crash is reported on firebase on Device HMD Global Nokia 8.1, I don't have a Nokia device to regenerate it but this crash seems Device specific. Also, it doesn't point any specific Code in my project.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10194 does not have permission to content://com.microsoft.office.onenote/clip [user 0]
   at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1950)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1918)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1868)
   at android.content.IClipboard$Stub$Proxy.getPrimaryClip(IClipboard.java:215)
   at android.content.ClipboardManager.getPrimaryClip(ClipboardManager.java:142)
   at android.widget.TextView.canPasteAsPlainText(TextView.java:11722)
   at android.widget.Editor$TextActionModeCallback.populateMenuWithItems(Editor.java:4007)
   at android.widget.Editor$TextActionModeCallback.onCreateActionMode(Editor.java:3939)
   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView$ActionModeCallback2Wrapper.onCreateActionMode(DecorView.java:2554)
   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.startActionMode(DecorView.java:1037)
   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.startActionModeForChild(DecorView.java:993)
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocess Webview needs to be activated. That is under Phone Settings -> Developer Options.

To activate Developer Options the multiple click method is used, There are multiple tutorial on the net.

Also, if is not device specific, then the first line în your Err Log can also come from the following:

- wrong format în the HTTP request string

- the [user 0] part shows that NO valid ușer was returned, does that ușer have a Microsoft Account ?